# How to Update Array dict Elements in mongodb based on another field

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

How can I update a value in a document based on applying functions to another field (which is in a different embedded document)?

With the sample data below, I want to

1. get the `col` field for the farm having `id` 12
2. multiply that by 0.025
3. add the current value of the `statistic.crypt` field
4. ensure the value is a double by converting it with `$toDouble`
5. store the result back into `statistic.crypt`

data:

```py
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "6128c238c144326c57444227"
    },
    "statistic": {
        "balance": 112570,
        "diamond": 14,
        "exp": 862.5,
        "lvl": 76,
        "mn_exp": 2.5,
        "lvl_mn_exp": 15,
        "coll_ms": 8047,
        "all_exp": 67057.8,
        "rating": 0,
        "crypt": 0
    },
    "inventory": {
        "farm": [{
            "id": 12,
            "col": 100,
            "currency": "diamond",
            "cost": 2,
            "date": "2021-09-02 18:58:39"
        }, {
            "id": 14,
            "col": 1,
            "currency": "diamond",
            "cost": 2,
            "date": "2021-09-02 16:57:08"
        }],
        "items": []
    },
    ...
}
```

My initial attempt is:

```
self.collection
    .update_many({"inventory.farm.id": 12}, [{
        "$set": {
            "test": {
                '$toDouble': {
                    "$sum": [
                        {'$multiply':["$inventory.farm.$[].col", 0.025]},
                        '$test'
                    ]
                 }
          }  }
    },])
```

This does not work as it applies to `test` rather than `statistic.crypt`, and I cannot figure out how to modify it to apply to `statistic.crypt`.

Comment: provied sample data

Comment: @mohammad Naimi 
I added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field can be updated based on another in the following stages:

1. add a field containing the farm
2. set `statistic.crypt` to the result of the mathematical expression (applied to the newly embedded farm)
3. remove extra fields

In code:

```
self.collection.update_many({"inventory.farm.id": 12 }, [
  {
    $addFields: {
      hh: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$inventory.farm",
          as: "z",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$z.id", 12] },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "statistic.crypt": {
        $toDouble: {
          $sum: [
            {
              $multiply: [{ $first: "$hh.col" }, 0.025],
            },
            "statistic.crypt",
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      id_pr: 1,
      id_server: 1,
      role: 1,
      warns: 1,
      id_clan: 1,
      statistic: 1,
      design: 1,
      date: 1,
      inventory: 1,
      voice: 1,
    },
  },)
```

Comment: and how can I, instead of "$first", that is, the first element, refer exactly to the "id" key to the array document

Comment: so you want to update specific array of farm ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, sorry for my inaccuracy

Comment: I tried it.  but there is a new problem, I described it in the question

Comment: "$inventory.crypt"  inventory dont has crypt field